# Bot Framework Skill - Invalid status code Unauthorized - reference to local path in stack trace

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, bots

I've been struggling to deploy a virtual assistant template bot and calendar skill for a while now. My progress is stalled here. I'm running the emulator against the Virtual Assistant deployed to Azure. The skill is also in Azure. The error is as follows:

```
Calendar Skill Error: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized' | at Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime.Prediction.ResolveWithHttpMessagesAsync(String appId, String query, Nullable`1 timezoneOffset, Nullable`1 verbose, Nullable`1 staging, Nullable`1 spellCheck, String bingSpellCheckSubscriptionKey, Nullable`1 log, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime.PredictionExtensions.ResolveAsync(IPrediction operations, String appId, String query, Nullable`1 timezoneOffset, Nullable`1 verbose, Nullable`1 staging, Nullable`1 spellCheck, String bingSpellCheckSubscriptionKey, Nullable`1 log, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis.LuisRecognizer.RecognizeInternalAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, Dictionary`2 telemetryProperties, Dictionary`2 telemetryMetrics, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis.LuisRecognizer.RecognizeAsync[T](ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at CalendarSkill.Dialogs.MainDialog.OnInterruptDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\GitHub\botframework-solutions\skills\src\csharp\calendarskill\calendarskill\Dialogs\MainDialog.cs:line 262
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Solutions.Dialogs.RouterDialog.OnContinueDialogAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.ComponentDialog.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext outerDc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at CalendarSkill.Bots.DialogBot`1.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\GitHub\botframework-solutions\skills\src\csharp\calendarskill\calendarskill\Bots\DialogBot.cs:line 47
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Skills.SkillMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AutoSaveStateMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Solutions.Middleware.EventDebuggerMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Solutions.Middleware.SetLocaleMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext context, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TelemetryLoggerMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext context, NextDelegate nextTurn, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TranscriptLoggerMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate nextTurn, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.MiddlewareSet.ReceiveActivityWithStatusAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.RunPipelineAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Since I see references to the skill's location on my disk I assume I'm doing the using the `botskill connect` tool incorrectly. This is how I'm invoked it. `botskills connect --botName SomeBotName --remoteManifest "http://MyCalendarSkill.azurewebsites.net/api/skill/manifest" --luisFolder "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\GitHub\botframework-solutions\skills\src\csharp\calendarskill\calendarskill\Deployment\Resources\LU\en\" --cs`

Should I point the luisFolder parameter at the same path in Azure? Am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Are you invoking the botskills tool from the virtual assistant project directory? Using the full path or relative path for --luisFolder parameter should be fine, as long as it's valid.

Comment: Yes, I was running the botskills tool from the VA directory. 

The latest pull from github resolved the issue. I'm not sure how, I must have made dozens of attempts on previous builds. I have a slightly stricter-than-normal security set up, I suspect, which might have caused a conflict with a previous build?